# display <li> depending on the value selected from the dropdown list

Tags: jquery, html

I want to be able to display the `<li>` on select of the dropdown option value.here is the html for the dropdown:

```
<select id="gridSelection">
<option value="0">Select a option</option>
<option value="1">grid 1</option>
<option value="2">grid 2</option>
<option value="3">grid 3</option>
<option value="4">grid 4</option>
</select>
```

My `<li>` is generated dynamically as follows:

```
<ul class ="gridContainer">
  <li id="widget">
   <img src="images/{{path}}" alt="" />
</li> 
</ul>
```

the list is generated using the json table data:

```
var serialize = [
    {
        "widgetId": "widget_0",
        "title": "Test Info",
        "description": "",
        "type": "info",

         "path":"test-info.png",
        "dataType": "TEST_INFO",
        "position": {
            "col": 1,
            "row": 1,
            "size_x": 1,
            "size_y": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "widgetId": "widget_1",
        "title": "Test Details",
        "description": "",
        "type": "info",
        "path":"test-details.png",
        "dataType": "TEST_DETAILS",
        "position": {
            "col": 2,
            "row": 1,
            "size_x": 2,
            "size_y": 2
        }
    }];
```

so in the above case, the first `<li>` generated would be the image with "Test-info" and id= "widget_0" and so on..

I'm looking to display the `<li>` that i select from the dropdown list using jquery.
Any ideas???Please feel free to ask for nay additional info if i may have missed any..

Thanks in advance....

Comment: do you have a class or id for those li elements like `widget_1` or `widget_0`

Comment: in abstract a solution might look like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5Cqe3/1/

Comment: yes, i do have the id for each <li> element, the                    <li id="widget_0"><li id="widget_1"><li id="widget_2">.However the <li> is generated dynamically, unlike the static: <li class="widget_0">widget_0</li>
    <li class="widget_1">widget_1</li>
    <li class="widget_2">widget_2</li>
    <li class="widget_3">widget_3</li> the 'id' im getting is through the json as you can see in the above code...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#gridSelection').change(function () {
        var id = '#widget_' + $(this).val();
        var $target = $(id).show();
        $('.gridContainer li:not(' + id + ')').hide()
    }).change()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5Cqe3/)

Comment: Thanks Arun..This wroks otherwise for a static list of elements, but I have a Json object that has images as content and 'widgetId':'widget_0', 'widget_1' and so on as you see above. How do I get that widgetid to display the content(image) i want to on select??

Comment: Something like this is what im using to get the id from the json field:                                                          <script id="widget" type="text/template">
    <li id="widget_{{widgetid}}">
       
        <img src="images/{{path}}"/>
    </li>
</script>